# Haystack: stats() and stats_results() doesn't work

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, elasticsearch, django-haystack

I have the following problem with Haystack and Django. That what I am trying to do is to filter the model Books some objects and get the max and the min price. Basically bellow is the query, where sq is dynamically generated query:

```
partial_query = SearchQuerySet().models(Books).filter(sq)
```

This return about 10 results.
After I checked the documentation of Haystack (http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html), found that stats('price'), stats_results() will work fine for me, but for some reason, the only output what I see is None. Below is the code:

```
partial_query = SearchQuerySet().models(Listing).filter(sq).stats('price')
partial_query.stats_results()
```

After a few test, I found that actually the following print do that, what they expect to do.

```
print(partial_query[0].price) #for example 123
print(partial_query) #list with about 10 objects
```

Also if you know any other methods to get max and min price from this query, please feel free to share with me :). I will be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your tags it sounds like you're using elasticsearch but as per the [haystack documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchqueryset_api.html#stats)

> This is supported on Solr only.